access github api from bowser
I am building a web application that should use github to store content and build websites. The last few days I tried to understand all the neccassery parts of the github api and also complete the oauth process, so I have a user token on my server. This is also nessaccery to store some information of the user on my database, but for most stuff the server would only be a proxy, so I would prefer to do request from the user web browser directly to github to avoid uneccassery jumps and load time.
As I could find out, the user access token is valid for about 8h, so it wouldn't be smart to store it in the browser, but I couldn't find any information on how to get a token like a JWT to use it in the browser. The only thing I found was to create an app JWT, but this does not have access to everything and if something has changed in github it should be mapped to the user and not to the app.
Is there a secure way to make requests to github on behalf of the user?

You need a client secret to obtain a refresh token (whenever the previous one has expired), therefore you need a server anyway. I'd rather route every API call through the server than keep track of token expiry and send one API call through the server every 8 hours.

By client secret you mean session token for your own server? But then your server acts like a proxy, which is at least one overhead I want to avoid. It is currently the only way I could figure out, but it feels wrong.

I meant the secret you obtained when registering your OAuth app.

Ah ok, clearly this needs to be stored on the server. It is also ok to have a server to do the authentication process, but if I use my server as a proxy in general to do the request I need to worry about localization, need to host multiple servers in different countries and so on, stuff I currently do not want to worry about. So the simplest solution for me seems to be to do the request from the client to github directly, because they already did all this. If it is possible...

According to GitHub Oauth documentation, neither implicit grant type nor PKCE are supported:

The implicit grant type is not supported.


The PKCE (Proof Key for Code Exchange) parameters code_challenge and code_challenge_method are not supported at this time. CORS pre-flight requests (OPTIONS) are not supported at this time.

This means that you are left with Auth Code Grant via Web Application Flow. This means that you need a backend to handle code exchange for GitHub access token.
It is easy to find a project on GitHub that implements such backend server. All you have to do is host it.
You may not need to deploy your own server. You may choose to use a SAAS solution that will do it for you, e.g. Auth0 that supports GitHub. You will need to research how to configure Auth0 to return GitHub access token to your browser.
Once Auth0 returns GitHub access token to the browser, you should be able to call GitHub API directly from the browser.
This solution should be much lighter than hosting an OAuth2-proxy that handles every API request, subject, of course, to the volume of traffic and the overall number of users.

Thanks, too sad :(. Auth0 just do the authentication, don't they? I also need more functionality from the api then just OAuth

Once you have GitHub user access token, you can use entire GitHub API on behalf of the user. Auth0 is a service to help obtain the token.
